# Convert.ToDouble raises a FormatException

Tags: c#, exception, formatexception

how can i skip a "System.FormatException" ?

Example:

```
    public void HowMuchBookCar()
    {
        Console.Write("\nOk, how much Euros you want to book in 'CarAndBeauty':  ");
        double howMuch = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        CarAndBeauty = Input(CarAndBeauty, howMuch);
        Save(@"C:\Users\tobia\Desktop\Neuer Ordner\JanuaryCategorie.txt");
        Console.Clear();
        WannaBook();
    }
```

This method is to book a specific amount into the categorie "Car & Beauty".
If the user would type here for example "G" (or something that does not work with this variable) it throws "System.FormatException" and the program stop working...

That makes sense ... but how can I prevent the exception from being thrown and instead a specific code?
(for example: "please make valid entry!")

Comment: Read up on "how to catch exceptions in c#" - e.g https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/

Comment: We really need a canonical answer for these types of questions, the ones that use Convert.ToX+exception rather than TryParse. It may not be the case here, but it seems like new devs are being taught to use the former and are never exposed to the latter. It's becoming increasingly more common. Are c# instructors and online tutorials all really that "bad". Yes Convert has valid uses, but handling user input shouldn't be one of them

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 so you mean it should be common to use TryParse ? I learn coding since november'20 , so im a total newbie.. i learned the basics from a online course... and until today i never heard of "TryParse" ... How you said : i learned it only with "Convert.To..."

Comment: I think that anyone with common sense would not try to catch an exception for parsing a double value. Exceptions are for, you guessed it, for exceptional situations, failing to parse a double isn't an exceptional situation. Futhermore, you probably know that exceptions are very slow. And main use for `Convert` class is for types implementing `IFormattable`, you can't really assume that console input is `IFormattable` by nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid `FormatException`, instead, use [double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0).

Here's how you could do it:

```
double result;

while (true) // until user has typed something correct
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input a number:");

    var line = Console.ReadLine();

    // NOTE: optionally here, you may want to exit program if say, user has typed 'exit'

    if (double.TryParse(line, out result))
        break;

    Console.WriteLine("Input was not recognized");
}

Console.WriteLine($"You typed: {result:G}");
```